# can't bundle install json gem in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, ruby, rails, gem, ruby-on-rails

I have installed ruby on rails using rvm . I am trying to bundle install an older project that I had on a former pc but I get the following error when I run the bundle install command:

```
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/florin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151003-5986-vme5ji.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/florin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/florin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Reading the internet I tried installing all the dev things like :
`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install libev-dev
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: please rename the question to "can't bundle install json gem in ubuntu" :)

Comment: i did rename it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp` means that the linker tries to link `lgmp` but can't find it.

Solution: Install the library needed: `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`

Related: https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253

Comment: that fixed the problem with json, and I thank you very much. Do I open a new post for the new one ? or update the existing one ?

Comment: Correct, please open a new question...

Comment: You are my hero.